# JQuery Show / Hide On Link Issue

Tags: jquery, html

I seem to be having a problem that I cant Find an Answer.

I have 5 A Href Links on a page that all have a matching div container ID. When clicked I want to hide all Div Containers except the container with the ID number matching the link.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar1">
<ul class="nav">
<li> 
- <a href="#" onclick="show1">1</a> 
- <a href="#" class="show2">2</a> 
- <a href="#" onclick="show3">3</a> 
- <a href="#" onclick="show4">4</a>
- <a href="#" onclick="show5">5</a> -
</li></ul>
      <div id="1">1111</div>
      <div id="2">2222</div>
      <div id="3">3333</div>
      <div id="4">4444</div>
      <div id="5">5555</div>
  </div>
```

I then have Functions set up. I have tried linking via Class and Onclick as you will see from above / below.

Script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#2").hide();
        $("#3").hide();
        $("#4").hide();
        $("#5").hide();
    })

    function show1() {
        $("#2").hide();
        $("#3").hide();
        $("#4").hide();
        $("#5").hide();
        $("#1").show();
    };

    $('.show2 a').click(function() {
        $("#2").show();
        $("#3").hide();
        $("#4").hide();
        $("#5").hide();
        $("#1").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: So what is your question? What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/KTGUx/)</kbd>

**Changed HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        - <a href="#" data-id="1">1</a> //data-id to get target id
        - <a href="#" data-id="2">2</a> 
        - <a href="#" data-id="3">3</a> 
        - <a href="#" data-id="4">4</a>
        - <a href="#" data-id="5">5</a> -
    </li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div_all = $("#1,#2,#3,#4,#5"); //cache all div's
    div_all.not('#1').hide(); //hide all but not element with id 1
    $('ul.nav a').click(function () { //user click on a tag inside ul with class nav
        var id = $(this).data('id'); //get data-id attribute to get target id
        div_all.hide();//hide all div's
        $('#' + id).show(); //show the current target div
    });
});
```

---

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

---

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

> Note: There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in
>   particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
>   with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes to do what you want to do without having to type out all those selectors:

```
  <div class="ShowDiv">1111</div>
  <div class="ShowDiv">2222</div>
  <div class="ShowDiv">3333</div>
  <div class="ShowDiv">4444</div>
  <div class="ShowDiv">5555</div>
  ...
```

then on your click handler

```
$('.ShowDiv').click(function () {
     $(this).show();                 //show the div that was clicked
     $('.ShowDiv').not(this).hide(); //hide all other divs in that class
});//$('.ShowDiv').click(function () {
```